# Integration of Facebook in native Android using SocialAuth

Tags: android, facebook, socialauth

I am integrating Facebook using SocialAuth library. I have downloaded and integrated Socialauth library successfully in the project. I am able to run the project and getting facebook screen while tapping on Facebook button. facebook is asking for credentials as well. i have entered the credentials but it is now always showing me error like "Invalid scopes, publish_stream. This message is only shown to developers......". and not able to login to Facebook. Please see the image.

Below code is written on "Login to Facebook" button

```
adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The permissions `offline_access` and `publish_stream` are deprecated, thus cannot be requested anymore

Try to download and import the latest version of the `SocialAuth jar` for android

Comment: I have downloaded jars from https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/. project is using socialauth-4.4.jar and socialauth-android-3.2.jar file. still getting an same error

Comment: replaced socialauth-4-4 with 4.8 and resolved the issue, Thanks Qadir

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line

```
adapter.addConfig(Provider.FACEBOOK, "YOUR_FB_APP_ID","YOUR_FB_APP_SECRET", "publish_actions");
```

above of

```
adapter.authorize(LoginActivity.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
```